# Kendo UI Upload Async Error

Tags: file-upload, telerik, kendo-ui

I downloaded a trial version of Kendo.UI, so logging onto the forums, at this stage is not possible, hoping someone on here can help me solve this problem.

I'm trying to implement the async upload onto a basic MVC 4 application. I've added a reference to the Kendo.UI.MVC wrappers, and added the necessary namespace Kendo.UI.MVC to both web.config files (root and under Views).

If I implement a basic uploader on my landing view (index.cshtml) it works fine:

```
<form action="/Home/Save" method="post">
   @(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("files"))
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

However, as soon as I add the Save() method to Async, I get an "index was out of range" exception. I know it's the save method, because if I just add "AutoUpload(true)" without an action reference, it does not throw an exception. If I just add "Remove("Remove", "Home")" it still shows the Select button, without an error, but the "Save("Save", "Home")" method keeps throwing the mentioned exception.

I followed the examples that ship with the trial to the letter and it should web working, yet it does not.

View (index.cshtml):

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Upload()
      .Name("files")
      .Async(async => async
                      .Save("Save", "Home")))
```

***-- Error is being thrown on the above statement***

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Upload()
      .Name("files")
      .Async(async => async
                      .AutoUpload(true)))
```

***-- this line works***

**Controller (HomeController):**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile> files)
   {
      // I just want the break-point to be hit
      // does not due to IndexOutOfRange exception being thrown

      return Content("");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated the MVC templates for Visual Studio and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that seems wrong is the Razor syntax:

```
(@Html.Kendo()
```

should be

```
@(Html.Kendo()
```

I was able to run your code with this small change.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but even with that change I still get the IndexOutOfRange exception.